# How to use FreeMono with THREE.js without complaints about holes

Tags: fonts, three.js

I've tried http://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/ with [FreeMono.ttf](https://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/), both with the "has holes" checkbox checked and unchecked. Both ways give me a 2.4MB js file. (The two versions are different.)

Whichever one I use in THREE.js I get "Infinite Loop! Holes left:1, Probably Hole outside Shape!", and the holes in the glyphs are not there. I.e. I get a blob instead of an "o".

Is there something about this font that won't work? Is there some hack I can do to make it work?

Comment: can  you show some example code that reproduces this?